# Redux thunk: return promise from dispatched action

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Is it possible to return promise/signal from action creator, resolved when Redux thunk has successfully dispatched certain action?

Consider this action creator:

```
function doPost(data) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: POST_LOADING});
        Source.doPost() // async http operation
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({type: POST_SUCCESS, payload: response})
            })
            .catch(errorMessage => {
                dispatch({type: POST_ERROR, payload: errorMessage})
            });
    }
}
```

I want to call some function asynchronously *in the component* after calling *doPost* action creator when Redux has either dispatched POST_SUCCESS or POST_ERROR actions. One solution would be to pass the callback to action creator itself, but that would make code messy and hard to grasp and maintain. I could also poll the Redux state in while loop, but that would be inefficient.

Ideally, solution would be a promise, which should resolve/reject when certain actions (in this case POST_SUCCESS or POST_ERROR) gets dispatched.

```
handlerFunction {
  doPost(data)
  closeWindow()
}
```

The above example should be refactored, so closeWindow() gets called only when doPost() is successful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can return promise from async action:

```
function doPost(data) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: POST_LOADING});
        // Returning promise.
        return Source.doPost() // async http operation
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({type: POST_SUCCESS, payload: response})
                // Returning response, to be able to handle it after dispatching async action.
                return response;
            })
            .catch(errorMessage => {
                dispatch({type: POST_ERROR, payload: errorMessage})
                // Throwing an error, to be able handle errors later, in component.
                throw new Error(errorMessage)
            });
    }
}
```

Now, `dispatch` function is returning a promise:

```
handlerFunction {
  dispatch(doPost(data))
      // Now, we have access to `response` object, which we returned from promise in `doPost` action.
      .then(response => {
          // This function will be called when async action was succeeded.
          closeWindow();
      })
      .catch(() => {
          // This function will be called when async action was failed.
      });
}
```

Comment: Can I ensure that then inside action creator gets called before then inside handlerFunction?

Comment: Yes. Code inside `handlerFunction` will always be invoked after `dispatch` code.

Comment: Also, for some reason example returns the Action object dispatched inside then and not the response

Comment: You should return `response` from `.then` function, if you want to handle response after dispatching async action.  You can check updated answer for more info.