# Of Redux Thunk, Sequelize (Bluebird) - returning promise to action creator "chain"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, sequelize.js, redux-thunk

So similar to some previous posts referenced below, I'm trying to chain `dispatch` through Thunk, however my difficulty is on the return from Sequelize. I can see the MySQL query hit the DB and return data, however that return is not flowing through the action-creator to the subsequent `.then`

I presume it's the manner in which I'm trying to use Sequelize - I'm new to it.

Many thanks!

Code:

`initDB.js`

```
...
export function sequelizeQry(qryName: string) {
  let query;

  // For later query mapping
  switch (qryName) {
    case 'POSummary':
      query = qry.spPOLedgerCardSummaryALL;
      break;
    default:
      query = qry.spPOLedgerCardSummaryALL;
  }

  return new sequelize.Promise(
    () => sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Returning promise: ', response);        //<-- This hits the console with data
        return response;
      })
  );
}
```

`database-actions.js`

```
// @flow
import { fetchingQuery } from '../action-creators/database-creators';

const fetchQuery = (qryName: string) =>
  (dispatch: *) => dispatch(fetchingQuery(qryName));

export default fetchQuery;
```

`database-creators.js`

```
// @flow
// Action Types
import { FETCH_QUERY } from '../constants/ActionTypes';
import { sequelizeQry } from '../utils/initDB';

/** Action-creators */
export function fetchingQuery(qryName: string) {
  const actionType = FETCH_QUERY;

  return (dispatch: *) => {
    dispatch({ type: `${actionType}_PENDING` });
    sequelizeQry(qryName)                          //<-- This gets called
      .then((payload) => dispatch({                //<-- Don't seem to get here
        type: `${actionType}_FULFILLED`,
        payload
      }))
      .catch(err =>
        // Dispatch the error action with error information
        dispatch({
          type: `${actionType}_REJECTED`,
          error: err
        })
      );
  };
}
```

Some other references I've checked:

1. [Redux thunk: return promise from dispatched action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329921/redux-thunk-return-promise-from-dispatched-action)
2. [return promise from store after redux thunk dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069212/return-promise-from-store-after-redux-thunk-dispatch)

Comment: Is `sequelize.Promise` a standard promise?  If so, you need to pass `resolve` as a parameter to the promise executor/handler, and then call `resolve(response)` instead of `return response`.

Comment: It looks like that was it, thank you so much. FLOW was nagging about requiring a `return` in a `.then` and I stopped thinking ... much appreciated!

Comment: Actually `return resolve(response)` makes FLOW happy ... I updated the below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to [adrice727](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3183170/adrice727).

Here's the code change for future visitors:

```
...
  return new sequelize.Promise(
    () => sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Returning promise: ', response);        //<-- This hits the console with data
        return response;
      })
  );
...

// BECOMES

return new sequelize.Promise(
    (resolve) => sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Returning promise: ', response);
        return resolve(response);
      })
  );
```